# Laravel get data from relationship table only

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller to get user but the output has relationship where the data is not come from db

Controller:

```
   public function test($id){

    $data = User::where("user_group_id",$id)->get();

    $tes = $data;
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Data Fetched',
        'payload'=>$tes,
    ],200); 
}
```

Output

```
"message" : "Data Fetched",
"payload" : [
   {
       "id":1,
       "username":asd,
       "profile":{
           "age:42"
        },
       "id":2,
       "username":sdf,
       "profile":{
           "age:60"
        },
```

etc

how can i access the data from the profile to group all the user by its age?

i expect the result like this logic

```
$data = User::all()->groupBy(profile->age);
```

thankyou in advance

Comment: Have you tried searching in the documentation and given it a try? There is a function `whereHas` to select on relations. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: im sorry but it doesn't related beacuse what i want is accesing the profile data to procces it, thank you !

Comment: You say you want to fetch the Profile based on the User. so `Profile::whereHas( ... ` will do that.

Comment: ah okay i will try. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the details of the relations between user and profile model but you should try something like the fallowing code to get the desired result

```
public function test($id)
{
  $data = User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('user_group_id',$id)
    $query->groupBy('profile.age');
  })->get();
  return response()->json(['message'=>'Data Fetched','payload'=> $data],200);
}
```

Comment: i tried but the error say i need to use wherehasMorph instead of wherehas.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way also

```
public function test($id)
{
   $data = User::where("user_group_id",$id)->get();

   foreach($data as $one)
   {
     $one['age']=Profile::where('user_id',$one->id)->first('age');
   }
   return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Data Fetched',
        'payload'=>$tes,
    ],200);
}
```